# convert the Mac address to HardwareAddr

Tags: go, ruuvitag

for the RuuviTags I'm using [this](https://github.com/peterhellberg/ruuvitag) package for converting the sensor data.
I try to convert the MAC address to the type [HardwareAddr](https://pkg.go.dev/net#HardwareAddr) as I'm using this via config for the scanning of ruuvi tags. but I'm struggling. In each way (using copy or via String) I'm not getting the right values. I end up with something like this:
��M�<
As the MAC adress is a [6]byte: how can I convert a [6]byte to [HardwareAddr](https://pkg.go.dev/net#HardwareAddr) ?

Example:

```
var hwSensor net.HardwareAddr
hwSensor,_ = net.ParseMAC(sensor.MacAddress)
fmt.Println("hwSensor (Cfg):"+hwSensor.String())
...
deviceRaw ruuvitag.RAWv2
fmt.Println("hw (Sensor)(RAW):"+string(deviceRaw.MAC[:]))

//output
//hwSensor (Cfg):e1:c7:4d:94:3c:2d
//hw (Sensor)(RAW):��M�<-
```

so basically I can easily convert a string (from the config) to HardwareAddr and get the string afterwards again (here: jsut for printing). But comparison of deviceRaw.MAC with hwSensor failes, as they do not match.

Comment: can you provide sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: added it above. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"how can I convert a [6]byte to HardwareAddr?"* -- Reslice the array to get a `[]byte` and then use a plain [conversion expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to get the `net.HardwareAddr`.

```golang
mac := [6]byte{0xCB, 0xB8, 0x33, 0x4C, 0x88, 0x4F}
addr := net.HardwareAddr(mac[:])
fmt.Println(addr)
// output: cb:b8:33:4c:88:4f
```

https://play.golang.org/p/5MWGs8R93-M

Comment: thanks!, the slicing was wrong at my approach.